# React Configuring Axios Path on Build

Tags: reactjs, electron

Most of my projects would be deployed locally and I'm using `Reactjs` along with `Electronjs` so I could build and run it as a desktop application.

The problem is that the `IP address` is different with every deployment and I would need to rebuild everything.

I have a file in the `src folder` containing the `IP address`.

Currently I'm trying if I could read a `js file` from the `build folder` containing the `IP address` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1.If your electron app run on the same enviroment with the page server, you can use 127.0.0.1:xxx/xxx to load the page.

2.If you server deploy locally and depart from the electron app, your app can read a config file in %appdata%. Write the correct ip in the config file.

Comment: If I run `npm build` it creates folder `build`(react) and `dist`(electron). I think you're saying that when react is hosted in a server then using the `IP address` of it on electron to display the website. I'm currently testing if I could modify it using webpack

Comment: Other way, maybe you can use file protocol to load react page?

Comment: I figured out a solution. I could actually edit the javascript files in `react` build that contains the `ip address` and the actual problem was that when the `electron` is built it does not actually take those changes and still uses the `old address` ... I tested it by opening the `index.html` and it does use the configured `address`.